# How to knit frequency tables with percentages to rmarkdown?

Tags: r, kable, gtsummary

I have a table like this:

```
1  2  3  4  5

A  B  A  B  A

C  B  B  B  B 

A  C  A  B  B
```

That I have been able to transform into this (thanks to your help!):

```
   A  B  C
1  2  0  1
2  0  2  1
3  2  1  0
4  0  3  0
5  1  2  0
```

My next question is: is there a package that allows me to knit that into a formatted table on a markdown document with percentages row wise? So that it looks something a little bit like this (but can be formatted?)

Would any know whether gtsummary or kable would be able to do these sort of percentage calculations? Also open to other packages. Thanks!

```
   A       B        C
1  2 (66%) 0 (0%)   1 (33%)
2  0 (0%)  2 (66%)  1 (33%)
3  2 (66%) 1 (33%)  0 (0%)
4  0 (0%)  3 (100%) 0 (0%)
5  1 (33%) 2 (66%)  0 (0%)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the proportions using `prop.table` and then use any of the package to display the table.

```
df[] <- sprintf('%s (%s)', as.matrix(df), paste0(round(prop.table(as.matrix(df), 1), 2) * 100, '%'))
gt::gt(df)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the gtsummary `tbl_cross()` function. Example below!

```r
library(gtsummary)

trial %>%
  tbl_cross(row = stage, col = trt, percent = "cell") %>%
  add_p()
```

[image]